# Geometry Nodes: How can I calculate the Minimum Position of indivudal meshes of one Geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: many individual meshes combined into one Geometry]

Hello,
I have a Geometry consisting of a bunch of individual meshes.
I want to calculate the Minimum Position of each of the individual objects.
In the end every individual object should lay on the ground plate.

[Here is my GDrive Link to the Blend File :)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CAif0yhaCXEwwnb1gZFlZJ2xOJLRsV_I?usp=sharing)

[image: The individual objects are floating above the ground]

Right now the objects are floating above the ground.

[image: my current Node Setup calculating the Min Position of the whole Geometry]
In my current node Setup I can only calculate the Min Position of the whole Geometry.
I do not know how I can get the Min Pos of each individual Mesh.

Comment: This not an easy task. These fruits are created by "extruding" a curve of varying thickness. Thus, the radius of each control point of each fruit curve is different. To put the fruits on the ground, you need to determine the maximum thickness for each fruit. In other words, you need the max radius of all control points for each spline (curve).